# How to spy update function in firebase admin SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, sinon

How can I spy on update function in firebase admin SDK below?

```
yield admin.database().ref('ref').update(obj)
```

I tried below but I can't

```
const databaseStub = sinon.stub();
const refStub = sinon.stub();
const updateStub = sinon.stub();

sinon.stub(admin, 'database').get(() => databaseStub);
databaseStub.returns({ ref: refStub });
const spy = refStub.withArgs('ref').returns({ update: sinon.spy(updateStub.returns(Promise.resolve(true))) });
```

Please tell me if you need more information to solve this problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps we can use `returnsThis` which is suitable to stub chain methods.

```
sinon.stub(admin, 'database').returns({
  ref: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
  update: sinon.stub().resolves(true)
})
```

Ref:

- https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.2.7/stubs/#stubreturnsthis

Hope it helps